# Can same IP address serve TCP/UDP traffic for load balancer forwarding rules?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I was trying to create forwarding rules using the `gcloud` command for say IP address `x.y.w.z` and I successfully created one for TCP port and when I tried using the same IP address for UDP traffic, it threw me an error suggesting that the resource `x.y.w.z` is already being used.

I thought for the Loadbalancer, the Unique combination is `[IPaddress, PortNo]`, unless I am wrong?

I was passing the value `ALL` for the parameter `--ports` for both `UDP` and `TCP`, I don't know if that's where it's going wrong.

Please correct me.

Comment: Which load balancer services are you using? Different load balancers cannot share global IP addresses. If you are using **one** load balancer include details on the configuration.

Comment: Please update your question with the commands have you used and their output if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create two load balancers (one TCP and one UDP) using the same external IP and utilising the same backend target pool (in my case it was a test GKE cluster). Both frontends were configured to route the traffic from port 53 (used in most cases by DNS service) to my backend.

[image]

For some reason it's not possible to have one LB with TCP & UDP functionality but you can have two doing the same thing. Not so obvious but it's a way.

To create those LB's I used Cloud console but [if you want to use](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/setting-up-network#configuring_the_load_balancing_service) `gcloud` here's an example (from the documentation) how to create it (assuming you already have target pool, health check and external IP):

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create www-rule \
    --region us-central1 \
    --ports 80 \
    --address network-lb-ip-1 \
    --target-pool www-pool
```